# RabbitMQ error(node:7932) MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am getting this error:

(node:7932) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Any ideas how I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Do a downgrade of nodejs

references:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29239

Comment: Node version 12.9 was not released yet when this question was asked